# Cleaner way to check if null

Tags: java, null

I have a class that holds a couple of byte arrays, some could be empty some not. And I want to return the first non null array (if there is one) or null if there isn't. But the code just seems so redundant and ugly.

```
public byte[] getFirstPhoto() {
    if (photo1 != null) {
        return photo1;
    }       
    if (photo2 != null) {
        return photo2;
    }
    if (photo3 != null) {
        return photo3;
    }
    if(videoThumbnail != null){
        return videoThumbnail;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there anyway to clean that up, or not really?

Comment: the last if is not necessary

Comment: @wero: It makes its intent explicit.

Comment: @wero and allows another case to be inserted after without changing the existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Write a method something like this:

```
public byte[] firstNonNull(byte[]... arrays) {
    for (byte[] array : arrays) {
        if (array != null)
            return array;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then call this function passing in your four arrays in the proper order.